# tsc not checking type equality/assignability correctly

Tags: typescript

## Observation

I found that my code editor (vscode) is not complaining about line 5. So I thought that it was just a typescript extension bug. But when I compiled it (`tsc`), it was successfully compiled.

```
class A {}
class B {}
class C {}
type X = A | B;
let x: X = new C();
```

## Further observation

When I defined `class A` and `class B` with some member fields/methods and leaves `class C` empty, then compilation fails. And I defined `class D` and `class E` with member fields/methods are the same with the either of `class A` or `class B`, then it compiles successfully

```
class A {public a: string;}
class B {public f() {};}
class C {}
class D {public a: string;}
class E {public f() {};}
type X = A | B;
let x: X = new C(); // fail
let y: X = new D(); // success
let z: X = new E(); // success
```

## Even further observation

In the above example, below gives me `false`, `false` and `true`.

```
console.log(y instanceof A);
console.log(y instanceof B);
console.log(y instanceof D);
```

## Question

Does `tsc` checks *type equality/assignability* not with *class name* but with *member signature* ?

(all tests done with `tsc --version` = `3.8.3`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, typescript has [structural type system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Structural_type_system).

> Type compatibility in TypeScript is based on structural subtyping. Structural typing is a way of relating types based solely on their members. This is in contrast with nominal typing

More info on type compatibility [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#introduction).

Comment: Thanks for answer. So the WA would be add some dummy member(s) to distinguish?

Comment: It depends on use case and reason to distinguish. Do you have any real life example?